# Submenu items do not stay on hover

Tags: html, css

The submenu items do not stay there upon hover. Upon hovering Portals for example, the ul displays, but does not stay there when I want to move down to click on it.

JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/42qg5/2

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About SRJC</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Admission</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">The SR Programmes</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CCAs</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portals</a>

        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">ASPIRE</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Staff & Parents</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding `margin-top:-1px` to your submenu items. It's the 1px space between the menu and the submenu that is causing this.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Nope, not hitting the point.

Comment: how about changing the padding on `#menu li a` to `padding: 10px 20px 14px 20px;`, does that work?

Comment: @Joeytje50 yes it does! thanks! may i know why?

Comment: I've added an answer to this question with the full explanation (it was a bit too long for a comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you need to set your padding on your `#menu li a` to `10px 20px 14px 20px;` instead, giving you the code:

```
#menu li a { 
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px 20px 14px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

To explain why this work, I first need to explain why this is going wrong in the first place.

You trigger the opening of the submenus by displaying it when the parent `<li>` is hovered over. This `<li>`'s child `<a>` has a set padding, but that padding does not stretch out the entire height of the parent menu `<ul>` element. Because of that, there's a tiny bit of space between the `<a>` and the submenu `<ul>`, which causes the submenu to collapse again when you try to hover over it: it has to move over just a tiny bit of space.

The increasing of the bottom padding then fixes this because it takes up that tiny bit of space between the `<li>` and the submenu `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need to use opacity:0 when you are using display:none, Secondly the ul doesn't stay because if you notice carefully there is a gap between the parent li and submenu. Overlapping submenu over the parent li at least 1px should do the job.

Also remove this

```
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
```

from

```
#menu ul li ul li {
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42qg5/5/)

Comment: Also, ul li will target all the li's, even in the submenu. Same goes for li a. If you want to target only the immediate li's you should use immediate child selector i.e. ul.parent > li or

Comment: If you've got something to add to the answer, you can use the "edit" button below it to add that to your answer. Usually that's better than commenting on your own question.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought this info wasn't directly related to the question, so I added it as a comment.